# Experiencing loop or previous error loading module error when loading the neosolarized plugin with Packer in Neovim

Tags: lua, neovim, packer, neovim-plugin

I am currently using `Packer` with Neovim and trying to load a specific plugin called `neosolarized`. However, I am encountering the following error message and failing to load the plugin:

```
neosolarized is not installed false loop or previous error loading module 'neosolarized'
```

Here's a part of my configuration file(`~/.config/nvim/lua/neosolarized.lua`):

```lua
local status, packer = pcall(require, "packer")
if (not status) then
  print("Packer is not installed")
  return
end

vim.cmd [[packadd packer.nvim]]

packer.startup(function(use)
  use 'tjdevries/colorbuddy.nvim'
  use 'svrana/neosolarized.nvim'
end)

local status, n = pcall(require, "neosolarized")
if (not status) then
  print("neosolarized is not installed", pcall(require, 'neosolarized'))
  return
end
```

I run `:PackerSync` and then open Neovim. Does anyone have any ideas on how I could solve this issue or what might be causing it? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was facing the same error, removing the `~/.local/share/nvim/lazy/LuaSnip` and reinstalling it fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I can solve this issue by myself.
I changed the filename from `~/.config/nvim/lua/neosolarized.lua` to `~/.config/nvim/lua/neosolarized_config.lua`.

Answer (score 0):

Naeem Baghi's solution worked for me. I'm using `Lazy.nvim` and got a similar error repeatedly when I pressed tab, but instead relating to `luasnip` instead of `neosolarized`. Other neovim (both Lazy and Packer) users have had the same issue with other plugins, and this solution worked for them too. So the general solution appears to be `rm -rf ~/.local/share/lazy/[plugin_name]` (in my case LuaSnip), then reinstalling the plugin (in my case this involved restarting neovim, allowing Lazy to check for uninstalled plugins and install them).